# React, React-svg. How to restore original colors

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I have a set of `.svg` icons *with different colors for different paths*. Currently I'm using [react-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg) package to render them and it looks something like this:

```js
<span>
    <ReactSVG
       src="/icons/setting.svg"
       beforeInjection={svg => {
         svg.classList.add("svg-classname");
       }}
    />
</span>
```

This works fine. Now I want to change all path colors to gray and bring all original colors back by user hover, Which I am trying to achieve in my `scss` by doing:

```css
.svg-classname {
      path,
      rect,
      circle {
        fill: #888;
        color: #888;
      }
      &:hover {
        path,
        rect,
        circle {
          fill: initial;
          color: initial;
        }
      }
}
```

This clearly doesn't work! Im not an expert with svgs so any suggestion (even outside of using `react-svg`) are truly welcome.

Comment: Two suggestions: try 'inherit' instead of 'initial', add 'stroke' along with 'fill'. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple D3 work-around for your problem:

```js
d3.selectAll('.my-svg-icon path')
  .each(function() {
    const path = d3.select(this);
    const originalColor = path.attr('fill');
    path.attr('fill', 'gray')
      .on('mouseenter', () => path.attr('fill', originalColor))
      .on('mouseleave', () => path.attr('fill', 'gray'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="my-svg-icon">
  <path d="M 10,10 H 50 V 50 H 10 Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
<svg class="my-svg-icon">
  <path d="M 10,10 H 50 V 50 H 10 Z" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks for replying